# What is meant by “relation between sets” in this question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A homework question asks,

> Consider any two sets $A$ and $B$. What should the relation between $A$ and $B$ be, so that $( ∩ ) ×  =  × ( ∩ )$. Prove your answer

I am not looking for an answer to the problem, but I’m not understanding what it is asking for. I think it’s asking “is $A$ a subset of $B$, vice versa, etc” but I’m not sure.

Comment: it could be $A=B$

Answer (score 0):

The question indeed asks you to find some inclusion relation between $A$ and $B$ such that the relation holds. Or some other condition that you should find.

You can start by observing that if $B=\emptyset$ or $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then the statement holds. Thus you can go on with the assumption that neither set is empty.

What can you conclude from $X\times Y=Y\times X$ if $X$ and $Y$ are not empty?